# Beautiful timeout handling

Tags: python

Help me please make this code less ugly:

```
try: 
        txt=urlopen(url, timeout=20).readlines()
except timeout:
        print ("Exception!\nWait...")
        sleep (20)
        try:
                txt=urlopen(url, timeout=20).readlines()
        except timeout:
                print ("Exception!\nWait...")
                sleep (20)
                try:
                        txt=urlopen(url, timeout=20).readlines()
                except timeout:
                        print ("No quotes...")
```

I want to do it in circle:
10 attempts

If 10-th attempt fails, it prints:

```
print ("No quotes...")
```

Comment: `while True: try ... except: ...`, with a `break` somewhere…!?

Comment: Or `txt = None` and then `while txt is None`. Make immediately clear what the loop is there for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to use python for loop?

```
isDownloaded=False
for i in range(1, 20):
  try: 
          txt=urlopen(url, timeout=20).readlines()
  except timeout:
          print ("Exception!\nWait...")
          sleep (20)
  else:
          isDownloaded=True
          break

if (isDownloaded==False):
  print ("No quotes...")
```

Comment: Thank You. It is what I want :)